# Asking User Multiple Times for Input in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, iteration, do-while

So far I have this:

```
package CashRegister;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CashRegister {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner askPrice = new Scanner(System.in);  
            for(double i = 0 ; i < 3; i++);  
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a value") ;
                double price = askPrice.nextDouble();
            }
    }    
}
```

How can I prompt the user for three values and add them together?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example I built on your code:

```
double[] price= new double[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
     System.out.println("Enter another ");
     double price[i] = askPrice.nextDouble();
}
```

Later on, you can iterator over the price array, and add all the values:

```
double total = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<price.length; i++) {
    total += price[i];
}
```

Comment: add try-catch to  double price[i] = askPrice.nextDouble();
} ;

Comment: you don't need 2 for-loops to calculate `sum`, you can optimize the code with single for-loop

Answer (score 1):

seems like a homework . So just a hint here. Try to learn and do by yourself with the help

To calculate the sum you need to declare a variable out of the for loop scope. so declare a variable say sum and after each input add price to sum. After the end of loop the sum will containt the result.

**Edit:**

we all missed a minor thing.. You placed a semicolon (;) after for loop remove this..

so use

```
for(double i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
```

instead of

```
for(double i = 0 ; i < 3; i++);
```

As you have used semicolon the for loop has a blank statement. So your input is not in the scope of for loop.

Comment: Yes, but how can I repeat the step to ask the user for an input three times?

Comment: you have already done that.. after showing enter value when user will enter the number and press enter the next prompt will show !!!

Comment: But it doesn't! For example, when I run that code, it asks me to enter a value. Once I enter, let's say "3", it prints "3.0". I need to make it where it keeps asking me for a value two more times. That's what I am asking. Thanks!

Comment: gotcha.. check my answer @User